# Error while compiling libjingle on windows 7

Tags: c++, google-talk, libjingle, hole-punching

I followed the README included in libjingle download. Installed all the 3rd party packages and ran this command:

hammer.bat --jobs=6 --verbose --mode=all all_programs

I get this error:

```
cl /Fobuild\dbg\obj\session\phone\videoadapter.obj /c session\phone\videoadapter.cc /TP /ZI /Od /MTd /RTC1 /nologo /W3 /Fdbuild\dbg\obj\session\phone\
videoadapter.obj.pdb /WX /Zc:forScope /EHs-c- /GR- /Gy /wd4996 /w14701 /w14702 /w14706 /w14709 /w14063 /w14064 /w14057 /w14263 /w14266 /w14296 /w14355
 /DLOGGING=1 /DFEATURE_ENABLE_SSL /DFEATURE_ENABLE_VOICEMAIL /DFEATURE_ENABLE_PSTN /DHAVE_SRTP /D_ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_W
ARNINGS /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T /D_UNICODE /DUNICODE /D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 /DWIN32 /DWINVER=0x0500 /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 /D_WIN32_
IE=0x0501 /DNTDDI_VERSION=NTDDI_WINXP /D_WINDOWS /D_DEBUG /DFEATURE_ENABLE_VOICEMAIL /DEXPAT_RELATIVE_PATH /DGTEST_RELATIVE_PATH /DSRTP_RELATIVE_PATH
/DXML_STATIC /D_LIB /Ibuild\dbg\obj /I. /IC:\code /IC:\wtl_71\include /IC:\include /Ibuild\dbg\obj\third_party\libudev /Ithird_party\libudev /Ibuild\d
bg\obj\third_party\expat-2.0.1\lib /Ithird_party\expat-2.0.1\lib /Ibuild\dbg\obj\third_party\gtest\include /Ithird_party\gtest\include /Ibuild\dbg\obj
\third_party\srtp\include /Ithird_party\srtp\include /Ibuild\dbg\obj\third_party\srtp\crypto\include /Ithird_party\srtp\crypto\include /Ibuild\dbg\obj
\third_party\openssl\include /Ithird_party\openssl\include
videoadapter.cc
c:\code\talk\third_party\srtp\crypto\include\config.h(188) : error C2371: 'int8_t' : redefinition; different basic types
        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(17) : see declaration of 'int8_t'
c:\code\talk\third_party\srtp\crypto\include\config.h(188) : error C2371: 'int8_t' : redefinition; different basic types
        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdint.h(17) : see declaration of 'int8_t'
scons: *** [build\dbg\obj\session\phone\srtpfilter.obj] Error 2

scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Environment details:

Windows 7

python 2.7.3

scons 2.1.0

Visual C++ 2010 Express

Answer (score 0):

**Successfully compiled libjingle** 0.6.14 by following this link : http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/issues/detail?id=242 [Used Visual Studio 2010 Professional].

- Mentioned link provides mylibjingle.rar, and that provides the solution file.

If encounter any issue :

- Open individual solutions file e.g. mylibjingle.sln,login.vcxproj, jingle.vcxproj
  and refer the list of source files.
- Compare this list with the libjingle.scons file e.g. To build jingle library it require set of files as mentioned in libjingle.scons files, and to build on windows it require to prepare similar visual studio project file.

  e.g : while building pcp_main.cc , it throw the linker issue related to : InternetQueryOption

  - Solution : added wininet.h on top of pcp_main.h and it worked.